# In terminal (Bash), how do you autocomplete partial matches in the middle of a filename?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, terminal

I have a bunch of files named things like:

```
2011-04-02-hello.rb
2011-04-02-bye.rb
2011-06-22-cat.rb
2011-06-17-dog.rb
```

Ideally, I could access the first file by typing `vim h<TAB>`, and it'd autocomplete the rest.

In terminal, how can I autocomplete a filename with a partial match in the middle of the name?

Comment: You can do that with zsh... what's your shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
vim *h*<ENTER>
```

*Shrug*

Comment: If you type `control-X *` before hitting `<ENTER>`, it should expand the wildcard.

Comment: Extra effort of pressing shift key then reaching out to the numbers row. Repeat this N times per day. For me N is maybe order of 100